# Topic:How to plot dynamic plot in python instead of constant staright line

Tags: python

I want to plot temperature vs frequency graph. I have used to y axis . But I am getting a constant line for frequency though I have 10 digits after decimal. i.e 15.01234567 etc .

How to solve it ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/at8IO.jpg]

Comment: which library you use to plot??
did you try to set the scale manually?

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot and numpy

Comment: no not manually, I got two y-axis ,left y axis is temperature and right y-axis is frequency. Other things are correct but I am getting straight line for frequency graph. My points are like this 15.0000156 15.0000546 15.000785 continues

Comment: import os
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = numpy.genfromtxt('My_file.dat')fig=plt.figure()
ax1=plt.subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()sat1=ax1.plot(data[:,0],'g-',label='temperature')sat2=ax2.plot(data[:,1],'m-',label='Frequency')sat=sat1+sat2
sut= [l.get_label() for l in sat]
ax1.legend(sat, sut, loc=0)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time data', color='r')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temp data', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Freq data', color='m')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\Check it Out!')
ax1.grid()plt.show()

Comment: assuming that your graph is callef gph try this: `gph.autoscale_view(True,True,True)`

Comment: Sorry no change ..